# data beeing pushed from cache

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, load

I have a website in asp.net with 3 language versions. I cache most of the frequently used data in cache using

HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, obj)

everything works ok I save the different language data with a unique key. I made a page just to see cache data and I can see all data in the cache for all 3 lang. versions. But after the site works ok for 2-3 days 2 of his lang. versions start working slower because the data is no longer in cache. When I load lang. ver. 1 data is in cache, but in 2 and 3 the cache page is empty. Then I load lang. version 2 data is cached, but for version 1 cache is empty.

For some reason it's like the data is being pushed every time new data is cached. After a couple of loads it fixes it self but this is s problem..

The site doesn't have memory restriction it can consume all memory it needs. In task manager I can see it's up to 130 MB Working Set Memory and up to 100 MB memory Private working set, handlers are never over 600. The App pool idle time is set to 0..

One more issue is at hand.. when you type the site in address bar and press enter it takes some time for the site to even start loading. I know because in the page with cache data load time very fast.. and I do mean fast.. but some times it takes like 10 sec. to load

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a timespan the cache decides when to remove items. This might not always be optimal. Try using the overloaded insert that is available and specify a long timespan.

```
public void Insert(
  string key,
  Object value,
  CacheDependency dependencies,
  DateTime absoluteExpiration,
  TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx for details

Comment: thanks for your response..
Maybe I'll try your way even though I don't want the cache to expire... ever. And I can't seem to find if asp.net sets a default value for expiration time in the case when doing it my way..